# Are X11 Release versions backwards compatible?

Tags: x11

I was recently looking at purchasing an old [X-terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_terminal). The server that runs on the terminal appears to be X11 release 5. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Release_history) table, the most recent X11 release was 7.7 in 2012. There's over a 20 year difference between these versions.

Are X11 Release backwards compatible. Would I potentially run into any issues with more modern X clients on an older X server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X protocol itself is stable in any given version, *i.e.* X11 in your case (see [What's the story behind the name "X11"?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3055/79)).

The differences between *releases* (X11R5 etc.) are mostly platform support, bug fixes, and most importantly, extensions. Many more extensions are available in R7.7 than in R5, and many of these are in common use now (ICCCM 2.0, RandR, Composite...).

So current X11 clients should be able to connect to the X11 server in your terminal; but many of them will require features which your terminal doesn’t support. Some might have fallbacks, but I wouldn’t expect that in general.